# Apply a function to every n elements of a vector

Tags: r, function, vector

This is actually a simple question, but nevertheless I can't figure out the solution myself.

I have a vector of length 100. Now I would like to calculate means for every five elements.

For example, one mean for the first five elements, a second mean for the next five observations, and so on.

How can I accomplish this in R?

Comment: But I find the suggestion of Ananda Mahto better than those under the link, because it is more intuitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
> x <- 1:100
> tapply(x, rep(1:(length(x)/5), each = 5), mean)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48 53 58 63 68 73 78 83 88 93 98
```

Sticking with `rep`, but trying to satisfy @Ferdinand.kraft, there is a less pretty but still pretty humanly-readable solution:

```
tapply(x, rep(1:ceiling(length(x)/5), each = 5, length.out = length(x)), mean)
```

Comment: This gives an error if `length(x)` is not a multiple of 5.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft, you write that as if this were a difficult problem to solve, but I know you know at least one solution ;)

Comment: `rep` has a length.out argument that palys nicely with the each argument

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
aggregate(x, by=list(0:(length(x)-1) %/% 5), mean)
```